# C言語関数のポインタ型（引き数、戻り値）がなぜ有値オプショナル型

Tags: swift, swift3

swiftからC言語の関数を使用するときに、ポインタ型の引数、戻り値がある場合、
インターフェイスは、有値オプショナル型となっていますが、なぜでしょうか？

例えば、次の関数のようなことです。

```
func time(_: UnsafeMutablePointer<time_t>!) -> time_t
func localtime_r(_: UNsafePointer<time_t>!, _: UnsafeMutablePointer<tm>!)->UnsafeMutablePointer<tm>!
```

例えば、time関数は、引き数にnilを与えることができます。
オプショナル型なので当たり前ですが。。。
だったら、標準のオプショナル型の方が理屈に合いそうです。

```
var current = time(nil)
```

また、localtime_r関数の戻り値は、有値オプショナル型ですが、
受け側としては、標準的なオプショナル型または、非オプショナル型で受けれると思いますが、
有値オプショナル型が戻り値なので、非オプショナル型で受け取っても安全だと言いたいのでしょうか。それだと、time関数の引数はの意味は？？？

なぜ、C言語関数のポインタに対する型が、標準のオプショナル型が使用されないのかを教えてください。

Comment: 標準オプショナル型は、変数にも要素にも使用できるけど、有値オプショナル型は、変数のみに使用できることに、何か関係ありますが？つまり次のような意味ですが。。。

var mark : [Int?] OK
var mark : [Int!] ERROR
var marl : [Int]!  OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftとObjective-C（C）ファイルの間にブリッジをするとき、ポインタ変数に、`nullable`、`nonnull`のオプションをつけないと、有値オプショナル（Implicitly Unwrapped Optional）型としてブリッジされるようです。

*SampleClass.h*

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SampleClass : NSObject

void changeValue(int * _Nonnull outValue, int inValue);
void changeOptionalValue(int * _Nullable outValue, int inValue);
void changeIUOValue(int *outValue, int inValue);

@end
```

3つの関数をSwift側から見ると、

```
func changeValue(_ outValue: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>, _ intValue: Int32)
func changeOptionalValue(_ outValue: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>?, _ inValue: Int32)
func changeIUOValue(_outValue: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>!, _ inValue: Int32>
```

こういう書式になります。
C言語標準ライブラリの関数は、`nonnull`、`nullable`をつけようがないので、しぜんIUO（Implicitly Unwrapped Optional）型の引数、返り値にならざるを得ないということではないでしょうか？明確な意図や、必然性があって、IUOにしているのではないと思います。